# Google Sheet: How to return array data in a horizontal way?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I write a custom function in Google Sheet:

```
function array_test() {
  return [1,2];
}
```

And test it in Google Sheet `=array_test()`:
[image]

You can see Google Sheet expands array data in a vertical way. But I just want to Google Sheet expands array data in a horizontal way, like that:

[image]

So, could anyone please give me some suggestion about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to put the returned values from the custom function to the column direction.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
return [1,2];
```

#### To:

```
return [[1,2]];
```

- When 1 dimensional array is used as the returned values, the values are put to the row direction.
- When 2 dimensional array is used as the returned values, the values are put to the row and column direction.
- For example, when `[["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]]` is returned to the cell "A1", the values are put to "A1:B2".

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the TRANSPOSE formula to your result, it gives you a script-free way to do this. Not sure if you needed to do your work in code to begin with, this is a simple alternative.